# Error trying to install libgreader

Tags: python

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ daniruhman$ pip install libgreader
Downloading/unpacking libgreader
  Running setup.py egg_info for package libgreader
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-build-daniruhman/libgreader/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import libgreader
      File "libgreader/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .googlereader import GoogleReader
      File "libgreader/googlereader.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .items import SpecialFeed, Item, Category, Feed
      File "libgreader/items.py", line 3, in <module>
        from requests.compat import quote
    ImportError: No module named requests.compat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-build-daniruhman/libgreader/setup.py", line 3, in <module>

    import libgreader

  File "libgreader/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>

    from .googlereader import GoogleReader

  File "libgreader/googlereader.py", line 11, in <module>

    from .items import SpecialFeed, Item, Category, Feed

  File "libgreader/items.py", line 3, in <module>

    from requests.compat import quote

ImportError: No module named requests.compat

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-build-daniruhman/libgreader
Storing complete log in /Users/daniruhman/Library/Logs/pip.log
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ daniruhman$ sudo pip install libgreader
Password:
Downloading/unpacking libgreader
  Running setup.py egg_info for package libgreader
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-root/libgreader/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import libgreader
      File "libgreader/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .googlereader import GoogleReader
      File "libgreader/googlereader.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .items import SpecialFeed, Item, Category, Feed
      File "libgreader/items.py", line 3, in <module>
        from requests.compat import quote
    ImportError: No module named requests.compat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-root/libgreader/setup.py", line 3, in <module>

    import libgreader

  File "libgreader/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>

    from .googlereader import GoogleReader

  File "libgreader/googlereader.py", line 11, in <module>

    from .items import SpecialFeed, Item, Category, Feed

  File "libgreader/items.py", line 3, in <module>

    from requests.compat import quote

ImportError: No module named requests.compat

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/libgreader
Storing complete log in /Users/daniruhman/Library/Logs/pip.log
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ daniruhman$
```

Any ideas?

Tried pip install requests:

> Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ daniruhman$ pip install requests
>   Downloading/unpacking requests
>     Downloading requests-1.2.0.tar.gz (341kB): 341kB downloaded
>     Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

Installing collected packages: requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

```
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests': Permission denied
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/private/var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-build-daniruhman/requests/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-OPYIXn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
running install
```

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib

creating build/lib/requests

copying requests/**init**.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/adapters.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/api.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/auth.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/certs.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/compat.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/cookies.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/exceptions.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/hooks.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/models.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/sessions.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/status_codes.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/structures.py -> build/lib/requests

copying requests/utils.py -> build/lib/requests

creating build/lib/requests/packages

copying requests/packages/**init**.py -> build/lib/requests/packages

creating build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/**init**.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/big5freq.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/big5prober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/chardistribution.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/charsetgroupprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/charsetprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/codingstatemachine.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/compat.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/constants.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/cp949prober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/escprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/escsm.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/eucjpprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/euckrfreq.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/euckrprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/euctwfreq.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/euctwprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/gb2312freq.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/gb2312prober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/hebrewprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/jisfreq.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/jpcntx.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/langbulgarianmodel.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/langcyrillicmodel.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/langgreekmodel.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/langhebrewmodel.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/langhungarianmodel.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/langthaimodel.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/latin1prober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/mbcharsetprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/mbcsgroupprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/mbcssm.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/sbcharsetprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/sbcsgroupprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/sjisprober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/universaldetector.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

copying requests/packages/charade/utf8prober.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/charade

creating build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/**init**.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/exceptions.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/request.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/response.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

copying requests/packages/urllib3/util.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3

creating build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/packages

copying requests/packages/urllib3/packages/**init**.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/packages

copying requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ordered_dict.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/packages

copying requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/packages

creating build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname

copying requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/**init**.py -> build/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname

running egg_info

writing requests.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to requests.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to requests.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'requests.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'requests.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

copying requests/cacert.pem -> build/lib/requests

running install_lib

creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests': Permission denied

---

Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-build-daniruhman/requests/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-OPYIXn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/47/1m2qc2sx65gf7zqyzzmdtvc80000gn/T/pip-build-daniruhman/requests
Storing complete log in /Users/daniruhman/Library/Logs/pip.log
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ daniruhman$

Comment: I think requests as requests library. Try ``pip install requests``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just confirmed by looking at the `setup.py`.
https://github.com/askedrelic/libgreader/blob/master/setup.py

It requires `requests` library.

Just do `pip install requests`.

Most of the time the error tells you a lot.